# Angular 2 ngModel submitting with ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

On form submit the data being repopulated back to the form is erring with `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

In renference to `<select [(ngModel)]="insurer.group.id" name="group" id="group">`

Template

```
<form #insurerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(insurerForm)">
    {{insurer|json}}

    <select [(ngModel)]="insurer.group.id" name="group" id="group">
        <option *ngFor="let group of groups" 
                [value]="group.id"
                [selected]="insurer.group ? insurer.group.id === group.id : null">
            {{group.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="dd_button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Insurer object

```js
{
  "is_admin": null,
  "type": "insurer",
  "group": {
    "id": 13,
    "email": null,
    "name": "Generic"
  }
  ...
}
```

Component

```
export class InsurerDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private apiService: ApiService,
        private location: Location
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getInsurer();
    }

    groups: Group[];
    insurer: Insurer;

    getInsurer(): void {
        const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.apiService.getOne(id, 'insurer', 'group').subscribe(insurer => {
            this.insurer = insurer;
        });
        this.apiService.getMany('group').subscribe(groups => 
        {
            this.groups = groups
        });
    }

    save(form: NgForm): void {
        console.log('trying to save data: ', this.insurer);
        console.log('form save data: ', form.value);

        // this.apiService.update('insurer', this.insurer.id, form.value).subscribe(insurer => this.insurer = insurer);
    }

}
```

I'm having issues with what I assume is the form trying to repopulate using the form data that it's sending on submit. Issue being is that the ngModel is trying to listen for `insurer.group.id` which doesn't exist. I tried changing ngModel to `[(ngModel)]="group.id"` and `[(ngModel)]="group"`but the issue is that it's not being populated on initial page load.

I've tried dumping the insurer object to see where the issue would be coming from with `{{insurer|json}}` but it doesn't appear to change after saving. So not sure how to go about debugging with the correct data.

Also tried overwriting the insurer object values in hopes that it would reflect with the code below.

```js
save(form: NgForm): void {
    this.insurer.group.id = form.value.group;
}
```

I'm lost on what I could do to resolve the error and keep the data populating on load. Changing `[(ngModel)]="insurer.group.id"` to `[(ngModel)]="group"` fixes the error but then data is not set on load even if I change the `value` attribute to reflect it.

Comment: add a "?" behind insurer in the template?

Answer (score 0):

one way is you to initialize `insurer` peoperty with Insurer instant like this

```
 insurer: Insurer = new Insurer() ; // this related to your implimentation
```

or

```
 insurer: Insurer = {group:{id:1}};
```

*ngIf

> use *ngIf and show form element if the `insurer` is initialize

```
<form #insurerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(insurerForm)" *ngIf="insurer && insurer.group">
    {{insurer|json}}

    <select [(ngModel)]="insurer.group.id" name="group" id="group">
        <option *ngFor="let group of groups" 
                [value]="group.id">
            {{group.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="dd_button">Save</button>
</form>
```

> you don't need to handle mark the selected option ngModel will do this for you `[selected]="insurer.group ? insurer.group.id === group.id : null">`

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmuear)

Comment: As far as I know, the safe navigation operator cannot be used with `[(ngModel)]`. See [this feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7697).

Comment: I have `ngIf` further up the page, since it contains more form elements that aren't represented here. It's checking if insurer is set and shows the form. If I were to check if `insurer.group` were set on save the entire form would hide.